# Determine if package was stopped and cancelling a task

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS Package that spawns a process.  If the job running the package is stopped while the process task is running, the process continues to run until completion.  Is there anyway to detect that the package is terminating and cancel the executing process?

Comment: How does your package start the process?

Comment: Execute Process Task